# How to use runas without being prompt for password?

Tags: visual-c++

How to use `runas` inside my code, without being prompt for password?

```
   SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};
   info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
   info.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
   info.lpFile = _T("IECapt.exe");    
   info.lpVerb = "runas";
   info.lpParameters = _T("test");

   info.nShow = SW_HIDE;

   if (ShellExecuteEx (&info))
    {
       WaitForSingleObject (info.hProcess, INFINITE);
    }
```

Comment: How would the system know the password of the user you try to run the program as?

Comment: @sharptooth iff the account is local then the password should not be needed.  However I expect the real answer is to mediate through a system service.  The implementation of Cygwin SSHD would be worth investigating the notes for Vista/7 support.

Comment: If your application is to be run with Admin rights, and current user is not admin, password must be given. Otherwise regular UAC prompt would ask for elevation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know user and passwort, you might use `CreateProcessAsUser`. But beware that `CreateProcess` and `ShellExecute` do different things.

You might also try to use `LogonUser[Ex]`+`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`+`ShellExecuteEx`+`RevertToSelf`, but I am not sure if this will work.